# soql on object permissions on a profile

Tags: soql, permissions, crud

I was trying to find out CRUD level permissions for a particular object on a specific profile for which I've framed below query:

```
SELECT Id,SObjectType,PermissionsRead,PermissionsCreate FROM ObjectPermissions where SObjectType = 'Account' and parentid in (select id from permissionset where PermissionSet.Profile.Name='System Administrator').
```

Now this is returning following result:

```
 Id                 SobjectType     PermissionsRead PermissionsCreate
 00000000lspT001AAC Account         TRUE            TRUE
 1104100000GpahYAAR Account         TRUE            TRUE
```

What is confusing me is that there are two results however it should have been only one . Can someone explain why we see two results

Comment: Maybe there are two permission set and both having permission on account object.

Comment: I am having the same. prefix `110` indicates, that it is `ObjectPermissions` sobject. But prefix `000` is not recognized. Interesting

Comment: I used the following code to get API name of sobject related to `Id`: `Id someId = Id.valueOf('1105000000AN85gAAD');
String sobjectName = someId.getSobjectType().getDescribe().getName();
System.debug('sobjectName: ' + sobjectName);`

Comment: This is a problem.  Specifically when I've given profile name as Sys Admin ideally it should have returned one result .

Comment: @Sagnik do you have to make this SOQL in apex ? if so, I have workaround for you

Comment: @OleksandrBerehovskiy Thanks! I'm actually doing this on JSForce and would use the result as a response to another system . Anyways the SOQL would be similar to that in apex

Comment: `000` key prefix represents the empty key. So filter out these records at your end.

Answer (score 3):

according to [Standard Field Record ID Prefix Decoder](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005995&language=en_US&type=1) I found few words about `X00` Id prefix:

> Found in the PermissionSet Name column where the ProfileId is also
>   defined. It matches the ProfileId with the exception of the key
>   prefix.

I'm not sure for what is it used. Looks like it is related to this situation. Waiting for other thoughts.

Workaround for you is to filter only needed `ObjectPermissions` ids. They are started with `110`:

```
List<ObjectPermissions> objPermissions = [
    select Id, SObjectType, PermissionsRead, PermissionsCreate
    from ObjectPermissions
    where SObjectType = 'Account'
        and ParentId in (
            select id
            from PermissionSet
            where PermissionSet.Profile.Name='System Administrator'
                and PermissionSet.IsOwnedByProfile = true
        )
    ];
List<ObjectPermissions> sanitizedObjPermissions = new List<ObjectPermissions>();
for(ObjectPermissions objPermission :objPermissions){
    String someId = String.valueOf(objPermission.Id);
    if(someId.startsWith('110')){
        sanitizedObjPermissions.add(objPermission);   
    }
}
System.debug('sanitizedObjPermissions: ' + sanitizedObjPermissions);
```

Comment: Got it! As of now I can proceed with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You might find this helpful: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387815&type=1

The gist is that behind the scenes every Profile is actually a permission set.
You can see which Permission Sets are just profiles and which are real permissionn sets using the field IsOwnedByProfile

```
SELECT Name, IsOwnedByProfile FROM PermissionSet
```