# How to access the "User" object permissions for a profile via Soql?

Tags: apex, soql

I want to know how can we fetch the "User" object permissions for a specific profile via soql query. I tried to obtain one using the ObjectPermissions Object but that resulted in 0 results.

Query I ran:

```
SELECT Id, SObjectType, PermissionsRead, Parent.Id, Parent.Name, Parent.ProfileId, PermissionsCreate, PermissionsEdit, PermissionsDelete, Parent.PermissionsModifyAllData
FROM ObjectPermissions
WHERE SObjectType='User' and Parent.Profile.Name = 'XYZ'
```

This query resulted in zero results.
Can we not fetch the 'User' object permissions or is there a way to fetch that programatically?

I also tried the solution as mentioned in [soql on object permissions on a profile](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/237238/soql-on-object-permissions-on-a-profile) but that also resulted in returning the zero results.

Comment: Nope. I tried running that as well. But still it return zero results.

Comment: Can you add more info on what you have tried from above article?

Comment: Only explicit permissions (i.e. setting to true) will ever be returned. Does the profile you're checking have any permission for User at all? A lack of permission is implied by not having explicit access granted.

Comment: @sanketkumar I ran the below query

select Id, SObjectType, PermissionsRead, PermissionsCreate
    from ObjectPermissions
    where SObjectType = 'User'
        and ParentId in (
            select id
            from PermissionSet
            where PermissionSet.Profile.Name='Agent')

Which gave zero results.

Comment: @PhilW. Yes I can create user with the profile using rest api, for which I am trying to fetch the results. For other standard object such as "Account" results are returned but when I try for "User" nothing is returned.

Comment: I think you can't fetch the User object permissions, because create/update access to Users is managed by 'Manage Users', 'View All Users' and few other permissions, not by CRUD permissions on Profile.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like we can't do query on `ObjectPermissions` object to fetch the `User` object permission but instead what we can do is fetch the `PermissionsManageUsers` field from the Profile object which the user is associated with and check the fields value whether it's `true` or `false`. If it is `true` then the profile has manage users permissions otherwise not.

Query:

```
SELECT PermissionsManageUsers from Profile where Id = '<PROFILE ID>'
```